# Adding layer of interpolated values to ggplot chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I have created the following dataframe in R to generate a plot using ggplot

```
 library(data.table)
 library(ggplot2)
 library(plotly)

     df <- data.frame("X_Frequency" = c(5, 10, 55, 180, 300, 360, 1000, 2000) 
       , "X_Axis" = c(0.009185742, 0.207822221, 0.067542222, 0.002597778, 
       0.002597778, 0.001454756, 0.001454756 , 0.001454756))
```

Next I have generated a plot using ggplot

```
        B <- ggplot(data = df, 
        mapping = aes(x = X_Frequency, y = X_Axis)) +  
        geom_line() + labs(x = "Frequency(Hz)", y="Axis")

        B <- ggplotly(B, dynamicTicks = TRUE)###Hovering enabled
        B <- layout(B, yaxis = list(type = "log"))##X Y log scales enabled
        B <- layout(B, xaxis = list(type = "log"))

        B
```

I have created the following dataframe df241 with interpolated values between various observations in df1. First we create the slopes

```
   df$X_Slope2 <- 0### Initiate slope column
   for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
   df$X_Slope2[i] = (df$X_Axis[i] - df$X_Axis[i-1]) / 
   (df$X_Frequency[i] - df$X_Frequency[i - 1])
                                     }
```

Next we assign the respective slopes to all values

```
     df_new <- bind_cols(df %>%
     select(X_Frequency, X_Axis, X_Slope2) %>%
     complete(., expand(., X_Frequency = 5:2000))
```

Now we calculate the interpolated values of X-Frequency, X_Axis from the df_new using slopes

```
       for(i in 1: nrow(df241)){
       if(is.na(df241$X_Axis[i]) == T){
       df241$X_Axis[i] = df241$X_Slope2[i] * 
       (df241$X_Frequency[i] - df241$X_Frequency[i-1]) +
       df241$X_Axis[i-1]  } else {
       df241$X_Axis[i] = df241$X_Axis[i]}}
```

I want to place these interpolated values from df241 on the original chart B generated above. How can this be accomplished. I request someone to help me.

Note:  I have tried generating a new plot based df_new dataframe. but the chart appears very different from the original chart -B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be simpler to use the `approx` function for your interpolation. I believe this gets a similar result as your interpolation steps.

```
df_interp <- approx(df$X_Frequency, df$X_Axis, xout = 5:2000) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rename(X_Frequency = x, X_Axis = y)
```

A linear interpolation may look unexpected on a log-log scale. I was unable to run your code as provided (is df241 created somewhere?), so I'm not sure if this is what you encountered when you said the chart with the interpolated values appears very different.

```
B <- ggplot(data = df, 
            mapping = aes(x = X_Frequency, y = X_Axis)) +  
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = df_interp, size = 0.1, color = "blue") +
  labs(x = "Frequency(Hz)", y="Axis")
B <- ggplotly(B, dynamicTicks = TRUE)###Hovering enabled
B <- layout(B, yaxis = list(type = "log"))##X Y log scales enabled
B <- layout(B, xaxis = list(type = "log"))
B
```

[image]

#### Edit: interpolation on log scale

Alternatively, you could interpolate using log-transformed inputs, and then use `exp` to convert back onto the original scale:

```
df_interp <- approx(log(df$X_Frequency), log(df$X_Axis), xout = log(5:2000)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(X_Frequency = exp(x),
         X_Axis = exp(y))
```

Which would result in this:

[image]

Comment: Yes. This issue is plaguing me. Is it possible to retain the black lines and have the points from the blue lines on the black lines. Mind you the normal scales in both look identical

Comment: Added another solution that addresses this. There's probably a smarter way to sample points to spread them more evenly on a log basis in the `xout = ` part.